# WebView Android application - how to read website content

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, webview

Basically I am designing an webview app which would work something like this...

**Pic Link** : http://tinypic.com/r/2z9060n/6

I have made a webview browser application as shown in the pic. Now I want to define a mechanism using which I can crawl the webcontent and get content say marked in Red in the pic. Based on this content I wanna call another API which will show a message at the green box down.

Any help in the regard would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: And you're browsing third party websites, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTML parser such as [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML page for the title / price of the item. Based on what the title and price are you can display a message using an overlay.

On a side note, the site is flipkart.com. You could also ask them if they have an API that they'd like to expose to you.

Comment: i used flipkart just as a random site. The site page can be from any ecommerce site.